# "Смотреть фильм в хорошем качестве"

Tags: грамотная-речь, фразеология

Здравствуйте. Почему-то режет слух сочетание "Смотреть фильм в хорошем качестве". Очень распространено сейчас на соответствующих сайтах. Понимаю "смотреть фильм хорошего качества". Правда, это скорее говорит о том, что фильм хороший. Или "смотреть фильм высокого разрешения" (в высоком разрешении?). Или "смотреть фильм с высоким качеством изображения".

Может быть растолкует кто, в чем я не прав? Почему режет слух и зрение :)

Answer (score 2):

Фильм "с высоким качеством изображения" или с прочими техническими достоинствами и есть фильм "в хорошем качестве". Например, в интернете можно смотреть фильмы или телепередачи в высоком, среднем и низком качестве.

А "фильм хорошего качества" - так про хороший фильм не говорят. Зачем два слова вместо одного?

Answer (score 1):

**Здесь можно провести аналогию:** хорошая музыка ― музыка в хорошем исполнении, хороший фильм ―  фильм в хорошем качестве (воспроизведения).

Фильм и музыка могут быть хорошими, но их исполнение или воспроизведение зависят от умения музыканта или от качества записи. Поэтому возникает необходимость в **различении этих терминов**.

Итак, есть хороший фильм, созданный автором, и есть фильм в хорошем (или не очень) качестве, который смотрит зритель.

Answer (score 0):

"Фильм хорошего качества" воспринимается именно как картина в высоком разрешении. "Хороший фильм" - уже просто хорошая работа, при этом хороший фильм может быть плохого качества и наоборот.

"В хорошем качестве", думаю, распространённый и допустимый в разговорной речи вариант. На письме лучше использовать другие формулировки.